# Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-stately/collections' in Next.js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextui

I was working on the Next.js app. I installed the `react-use` package in my Next.js project!
Suddenly Next.js started throwing errors!

[image: error]

Then, I searched for similar errors on Stackoverflow. Some of them suggested removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and trying to reinstall npm packages. I did so, but nothing seems working! Then restarted VSCode and computer, but the error was still there!

Even I tried to install that package, which is shown in error, but again it throwing an error for another package.

I am not sure why suddenly started throwing errors!

This is my `package.json`

[image: package.json]

I tried to update NextUI's latest version which is `"@nextui-org/react": "^1.0.0-beta.9"`

My current `package.json` file, after updating the NextUI

[image: new package.json]

Comment: Have you tried doing an `npm install @nextui-org/react@latest` ? The Dropdown component is apparently very new has a few other issues that were reported resolved in `beta.8`.

Comment: Yes, tried but the same issue!

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : make sure you add the 'use client' on the top of the file with the recently added component. This has something to do with nextjs SSR

Answer (score -1):

Try to clean the cache and delete `node_modules` then install it again

```
npm cache verify

npm cache clean --force
```

Delete `node_modules`

```
npm install
```

Comment: Did this actually work? Generally you shouldn't have to ever delete your `node_modules`. The reason deleting it sometimes fixes things is because the cache is in the directory (along with the downloaded packages) but if you've already done a cache clean, deleting is unnecessary.

Comment: It didn't work for me deleting the cache. I am in the process of deleting and reinstalling the node modules to see if it works....

...no, same error.
``` Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-stately/collections ```